# Apache Drill: Not able to query the database

Tags: hdfs, apache-drill

I am using UBUNTU 14.04.

I have started to explore about querying HDFS using apache drill, installed it my local system and configured the Storage plugin to point remote HDFS. Below is the configuration setup:

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "enabled": true,
    "connection": "hdfs://devlpmnt.mycrop.kom:8020",
    "workspaces": {
        "root": {
            "location": "/",
            "writable": false,
            "defaultInputFormat": null
         }
    },
    "formats": {
        "json": {
            "type": "json"
        }
    }
}
```

After creating a json file "rest.json", I passed the query:

```
select * from hdfs.`/tmp/rest.json` limit 1
```

I am getting following error:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 18: Table 'hdfs./tmp/rest.json' not found
```

I would appreciate if someone tries to help me figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!!